# trying to install Astromenace on my linux mint 14 cinnamon pc

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, installation

so i am following this tutorial as it is the only one i can find and any that i can find are the same as this one:

http://linuxg.net/games-on-linux-how-to-install-astromenace-on-ubuntu-and-fedora/

but when i type in the first command i gives me this

```
myname@myname-System-Product-Name ~ $ sudo wget -q -O- http://archive.getdeb.net/getdeb-archive.key | apt-key add -
[sudo] password for myname: ERROR: This command can only be used by root.
```

i really want to play this game and any help would be greate